# Sort table column into row with alphabetical order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an example table like this and I want to sort the entry column which is region, country, city value from columns into rows in alphabetical order based on the orderID column using a SQL query.

| list | orderID | entry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| list1 | AA | Asia |
| list1 | AAA | Japan |
| list1 | AAB | Thailand |
| list1 | AB | Europe |
| list1 | ABA | Germany |
| list1 | ABAA | Berlin |
| list1 | ABAB | Munich |
| list1 | ABAC | Hamburg |

Expected output:

| list | Region | Country | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| list1 | Asia | Japan |  |
| list1 | Asia | Thailand |  |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Berlin |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Munich |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Hamburg |

Comment: Maybe you could explain how the OrderId column is used to differentiate between Region, Country & City? Maybe you could also explain what options you have considered/tried and where you got stuck? Lets be honest that is a very unhelpful way to store data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of window functions for this, which will most likely perform better than 3 joins.

```
declare @MyData table (list varchar(5), orderID varchar(4), [entry] varchar(12));

insert into @MyData (list, orderID, [entry])
values
('list1', 'AA', 'Asia'),
('list1', 'AAA', 'Japan'),
('list1', 'AAB', 'Thailand'),
('list1', 'AB', 'Europe'),
('list1', 'ABA', 'Germany'),
('list1', 'ABAA', 'Berlin'),
('list1', 'ABAB', 'Munich'),
('list1', 'ABAC', 'Hamburg');

with cte as (
    select list
        -- Determine the region by partitioning of the 1st 2 characters
        , max(case len(orderId) when 2 then [entry] else null end) over (partition by substring(orderId, 1, 2)) Region
        -- Determine the country by partitioning of the 3rd character
        , max(case len(orderId) when 3 then [entry] else null end) over (partition by substring(orderId, 1, 3)) Country
        -- Determine the city by checking the 4th character
        , case len(orderId) when 4 then [entry] else null end City
        -- Determine whether a city exists for the country, if not, show the country with a null city
        , max(case len(orderId) when 4 then [entry] else null end) over (partition by substring(orderId, 1, 2)) City1
    from @MyData
)
select list, Region, Country, City
from cte c1
where City is not null
or (Country is not null and City1 is null);
```

Returns:

| list | Region | Country | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| list1 | Asia | Japan | NULL |
| list1 | Asia | Thailand | NULL |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Berlin |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Munich |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Hamburg |

Note that providing the DDL+DML as I have shown will almost certainly ensure you get answers faster.

Answer (score 1):

We use inner join to attach the countries to the continents and another inner join to attach the cities to the countries.

```
select   list, region, country, city
from     (
         select   t.list
                 ,t2.entry as region
                 ,t3.entry as country
                 ,case when t.entry != t3.entry then t.entry end as city
                 ,case when count(*) over(partition by t3.entry) > 1 and t3.entry = t.entry then 1 end as mrk
                 ,t.orderID
         from     t join t t2 on t2.orderID in(left(t.orderID, 2)) and t.entry != t2.entry join t t3 on t3.orderID in(left(t.orderID, 3)) 
         ) t
where    mrk is null
order by t.orderID
```

| list | region | country | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| list1 | Asia | Japan | null |
| list1 | Asia | Thailand | null |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Berlin |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Munich |
| list1 | Europe | Germany | Hamburg |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bwRvWbkm)